# Setting up my own private Astonia server

Tags: mysql

recently Astonia 3 went open source so people could host their own servers.

We got some info on how to do this on: http://brockhaus.org/astonia3.html

I've imported my .sql files and changed the password, however I can't seem to start my server nor do I know how?

I've noticed there's a start.exe file in it, but whenever I run that I get an error that it can't find /home/builder/log9.txt - I have no clue what this is, or if I even need it.

I've been asking some people but all they said was "Start the chat server first", but I can't find any .exe file for the chatserver

So anyone that wants to figure this out with me?

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it on CentOS, not in windows. The game first needs to be compiled, and then executed. I suggest reading up on "Linux / CentOS" a bit first, before attempting.

A running example can be found at: http://ugaris.com